# Error when trying to connect to DB2 Server

Tags: java, db2

I'm encountering this error when trying to gain connection to a External DB...

```
om.ibm.db2.jcc.b.DisconnectException: A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: Reply.fill(). Communication API being used: InputStream.read(). Location where the error was detected: Connection reset. Communication function detecting the error: *. Protocol specific error codes(s) TCP/IP SOCKETS   DB2ConnectionCorrelator: null
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.a.a(a.java:373)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gb.b(gb.java:191)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gb.c(gb.java:238)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gb.c(gb.java:353)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.gb.v(gb.java:1362)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.hb.a(hb.java:43)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.e(b.java:1389)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.b(b.java:1264)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.s(b.java:1036)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.b(b.java:744)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.a(b.java:730)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.b.<init>(b.java:331)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:165)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
        at com.interblocks.common.db.ConnectionFactory.getCon(ConnectionFactory.java:282)
        at com.interblocks.common.db.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:203)
        at com.interblocks.common.db.ConnectionFactory.getDataBasePlatform(ConnectionFactory.java:1073)
        at com.interblocks.common.sequence.c.<clinit>(Const.java:60)
        at com.interblocks.common.sequence.Sequence.<init>(Sequence.java:207)
        at irecon.Servlet_ReconTxnMgmt.<init>(Servlet_ReconTxnMgmt.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have no idea if its a code error or a network problem or DB error , please I do want to know why this exception triggered..and what are the things to consider to prevent encountering this?? Thanks

Comment: I'd start by looking at network issues.  Q: Can you "ping" the DB2 server?  Q: Is there a firewall between your Java client and the DB2 server.  Etc. etc.

Comment: Yes the ping is Okay...I'm not actually encountering any Request time out...

Comment: What about the port? have you done a 'telnet server instancePort' like 'telnet 192.168.0.1 50000'

Comment: Im not familiar with telnet server.. im connecting to an inet network actually..

Answer (score 3):

Ping is used to check if a server is alive. Telnet, normally allows to use the telnet service, but it can be used to check if a port is open (firewall) for remote connections.

You should check connectivity from the client

```
telnet db2serverName db2Port
```

For example

```
telnet 192.168.0.1 50000
```

Once you have checked that the DB2 port is open for your client, you should establish the connection or receive a different error message.